# clang set metadata to allocainst

Tags: clang, metadata, llvm, llvm-ir

First I'm real noob with clang/llvm.

BUT I'm trying to modify clang for some purpose.

I'd like to add metadata whenever an Alloca instruction is emitted in IR code for a variable which has some annotation.

I noticed this function in CGDecl.cpp:

```
CodeGenFunction::AutoVarEmission
CodeGenFunction::EmitAutoVarAlloca(const VarDecl &D)
```

which contains the nice line in the end:

```
 if (D.hasAttr<AnnotateAttr>())
      EmitVarAnnotations(&D, emission.Address);
```

this looks like the condition I need, so I modified it to

```
if (D.hasAttr<AnnotateAttr>()) {
      AnnotateAttr* attr = D.getAttr<AnnotateAttr>();
      if(attr->getAnnotation() == "_my_custom_annotation_") {
          // set metadata...
      }
      EmitVarAnnotations(&D, emission.Address);
  }
```

my Issue is I don't know how to add metadata at this point, because I can't find a way to access the instruction

In CGExp.cpp, however, I see where the AllocaInstr is built, but at this point I don't have access to the VarDecl, so I don't know if the annotation is there.

I tried anyway to add metadata (unconditionaly) in this function:

```
    llvm::AllocaInst *CodeGenFunction::CreateIRTemp(QualType Ty,
                                                const Twine &Name) {
  llvm::AllocaInst *Alloc = CreateTempAlloca(ConvertType(Ty), Name);
  // FIXME: Should we prefer the preferred type alignment here?
  CharUnits Align = getContext().getTypeAlignInChars(Ty);

  // how to put it conditionaly on the annotation?
  llvm::MDNode* node = getRangeForLoadFromType(Ty);
  Alloc->setMetadata("_my_custom_metadata", node);
  Alloc->setAlignment(Align.getQuantity());
  return Alloc;
}
```

by adding the setMetadata call.

However I don't see the metadata attached in the generated IR.

I compile with `clang -g -S -target i686-pc-win32 -emit-llvm main.cpp -o output.ll`

Maybe I'm totally wrong, but the thing is I don't master the code generation in clang :)

PS: here is the code I compile

```
int main() {
    __attribute__ ((annotate("_my_custom_annotation_"))) float a[12];
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (D.hasAttr<AnnotateAttr>()) {
      AnnotateAttr* attr = D.getAttr<AnnotateAttr>();
      if(attr->getAnnotation() == "_my_custom_annotation_") {
          // set metadata...
      }
      EmitVarAnnotations(&D, emission.Address);
  }
```

Looks like you are at the right place. In fact all `EmitAutoVarAlloca` has special handling for different kinds of variable declarations, but all end with the "address" (i.e., the instruction) in `emission.Address`.

So what you want to do is:

```
if (D.hasAttr<AnnotateAttr>()) {
      AnnotateAttr* attr = D.getAttr<AnnotateAttr>();
      if(attr->getAnnotation() == "_my_custom_annotation_") {
          emission.Address->setMetadata(...); // <--- your MDNode goes here
      }
      EmitVarAnnotations(&D, emission.Address);
  }
```

However, I would recommend a special attribute for adding metadata to instructions. If you read further through the code you will see that the `AnnotateAttr` has a special meaning and your emitted IR may not be as expected. You can add a custom attribute in the `Attr.td` file. I suggest a copy of the Annotate entry. Then you can follow the `AnnotateAttr` through the code and add code for your Attribute at the right places to get it recognized and handled by clang.

Comment: @Michael Haidl, I tried the same code, it complains: clang::CodeGen::Address’ has no member named ‘setMetadata’. Do you know how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ignorer emission.Address  has changed from `llvm::Instruction*` to `clang::CodeGen::Address`. Address is now a wrapper for a `llvm::Value*` which you must cast to an Instruction (do a dyn_cast with a nullptr check to be realy sure that you haven an instruction). On the instruction you can call `setMetadata` as in the answer.

Comment: @MichaelHaidl What if we don't have the 'address' and we want to add this code on 'EmitVarDecl' ?  I can't find where to attach the new 'Metadata'.